# Как заменить символы !@#$%^& на простые?

Tags: asp.net, c#

Как перевести в специальные теги (вроде `$nbsp;`) такие символы как : `!@#$%^&()`.
так как при загрузке файла на сервер (процесс загрузки успешен), но при открытии того файла которую загрузили выдает ошибку...

server.htmlencode()- не помогает.

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Как насчет старой доброй Base64-кодировки?

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно заменить на специальный html-тег на которую бы сервер не ругулся... может вы знаете какие то встроенные библиотеки. прошу помочь вопрос сильно нужен

Comment: Не до конца понятно 2 вещи:

1. Сам вопрос ( в чем сложность )

2. Чем не устраивает http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

Comment: Еще можно использовать регулярные выражения. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример ошибки. Где именно символы -- в имени файла? В HTML -- но тогда причём тут файл? Или сервер вставляет имя файла в HTML не экранируя -- тогда это проблема сервера, а не имени файла.

Comment: Side note: это не теги, а сущности (entities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку Вы не предоставляете полной информации, рискну предположить, что вам нужно

```
var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unencoded);
```

Для сервера на ASP подошёл бы совет отсюда: [New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

В среде WPF (разметке) для представления специальных символов применяется способ:

```
Символ  Запись в разметке
   <           &lt;
   >           &gt;
   "           &quot;
   &           &amp;
```

Точка с запятой обязательна.

Comment: Тоже самое в вебе, только как уже сказали выше для этого не нужен велик - есть средства готовые к использованию.