# XML. Заменить спецсимволы без изменения HTML тегов

Tags: c#, xml

Надо сохранить в `XML` текст. Например:

```
<p>"Hello">'hello'
```

Чтобы получить результат:

```
<p>&quot;Hello&quot;&gt;&apos;hello&apos;
```

Текст XML не может содержать спецсимволов:

```
" & < > '
```

Их надо заменять эквивалентами:

```
&quot; &amp; &lt; &gt; &apos;
```

Как заменить спецсимволы, но оставить нетронутыми теги `HTML`?

Вариант, который предлагают как дубликат этого вопроса, не возвращает нужный результат.

```
var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<p>\"Hello\">'hello'</p>");
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470236/220553

Comment: @defaultlocale ни разу не дубликат: там asp.net используется, а тут - xml формируется

Comment: @PavelMayorov Дубликат в том смысле, что ответ подойдет и здесь. [`System.Web`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility(v=vs.110).aspx) можно подключить к не ASP проекту. Если ответ по каким-то причинам не подходит, то стоит уточнить по каким именно, чтобы отвечающие не повторяли ответ.

Comment: @defaultlocale нет смысла. XML же обычно формируется не строкой, а через DOM, Linq2Xml или хотя бы XmlWriter. Все три варианта умеют делать экранирование. Фактически, при работе с XML в C# сложнее убрать экранирование чем добавить его.

Comment: @defaultlocale кроме того, не забывайте: на закрытый вопрос нельзя дать нового ответа. То есть отмечая вопрос про XML как дубликат вопроса про asp.net вы запрещаете другим давать xml-специфичные ответы. А это неправильно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, но сейчас вопрос о замене символов в тексте (строке). В вопросе нет ничего про формирование XML. Если автор его сформировал сам (не факт) и вопрос о включении экранирования, то в вопросе нужно рассказать об этом.

Comment: @defaultlocale первая строчка: *"Надо сохранить в XML текст."*

Comment: @PavelMayorov заголовок «Заменить спецсимволы, оставить теги HTML» :) Я не вижу в вопросе ничего про формирование XML. Если Вы видите и представляете XML-специфичный ответ, то предлагаю Вам его написать.

Comment: Вот, кстати, *"оставить теги HTML"* - отдельная проблема, которая там куда вы дали ссылку не раскрыта совершенно...

Comment: @defaultlocale я его как раз и писал пока вы спорили... Попробуйте найти куда там можно засунуть HttpUtility.HtmlEncode :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov вижу, поставил плюс. Отзываю голос, раз уж вопрос получил столь всесторонний ответ. Остаюсь при мнении что вопрос требует уточнения и частично был отвечен ранее. Ваш пост отвечает как минимум на три разных вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заменить символы !@#$%^& на простые?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170974/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Comment: Не дубликат! прежде чем редактировать - проверьте результат из другой темы с тем, что мне надо получить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего было бы если бы не требовалось сохранять тэгов. Как известно, есть 3 API для формирования XML - DOM, Linq 2 XML и XmlWriter. Все три умеют автоматически экранировать все строки (и автоматически же убирать экранирование при чтении XML):

```
string text = "\"Hello\">'hello'";

/* XML DOM */
XmlNode node = ...;
node.InnerText = text;

/* Linq 2 XML */
XElement node = ...;
node.Value = text;
node.Add(text); // или так

/* XmlWriter  */
XmlWriter writer = ...;
writer.WriteValue(text);
```

Если нужно добавить сюда HTML-тэги в неэкранированном виде, то все сложнее. Для начала, HTML попросту несовместим с XML напрямую, и это придется учитывать. В частности, любой тэг в XML должен быть закрыт.

Вторая проблема заключается в том, что HTML-тэги нужно еще как-то отделить от текста. Проще всего если вы их формируете программно: в таком случае их можно просто изначально не смешивать:

```
string text = "\"Hello\">'hello'";

/* XML DOM */
XmlDocument doc = ...;
XmlElement node = ...;

var p = doc.CreateElement("p");
p.InnerText = text;
node.AppendChild(p);

node.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("p")).InnerText = text; // или вот так еще можно

/* Linq 2 XML */
XElement node = ...;
node.Add(new XElement("p", text));

/* XmlWriter  */
XmlWriter writer = ...;
writer.WriteStartElement("p");
writer.WriteValue(text);
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Если же разделить разметку и текст еще на этапе формирования не получается - придется использовать HTML-парсер. Например, [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/):

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml("<p>\"Hello\">'hello'");
htmlDoc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;

/* XmlWriter */
XmlWriter writer = ...;
htmlDoc.Save(writer);

/* Linq 2 XML */
XElement node = ...;
using (var writer = node.CreateWriter())
    htmlDoc.Save(writer);

/* XMl DOM */
XmlElement node = ...;

var w = new StringWriter();
htmlDoc.Save(w);
node.InnerXml = w.ToString();
```

Comment: на вход подается именно строка `<p>"Hello">'hello'` которую, после приведения к нужному виду, я через XmlCDataSection добавлю в xml.

Comment: @AleksandrH. а в чем в таком случае проблема-то?

Comment: Использовав Ваш пример, получил `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="koi8-r"?><p>&quot;Hello&quot;&gt;'hello'</p>` , а хотел `<p>&quot;Hello&quot;&gt;&apos;hello&apos;</p>`

Comment: @AleksandrH. а в чем смысл? Чем вас апострофы не устраивают?

Comment: такое требование к формированию xml файла. Решение: дальше через replace убрать обявление xml и заменить апострофы?

Comment: @AleksandrH. объявление xml убрать если будете сохранять XML через XmlWriter с настройкой OmitXmlDeclaration

Comment: @AleksandrH. ну а апострофы можете и правда заменять регуляркой. Но лучше объяснить что это требование ничем не обосновано.